# Italic a Persian word in Xelatex using overleaf

Tags: xetex, italic

I'm trying to write a word in italic in Xelatex using overleaf. 
But `\textit` doesn't work for persian words unless I upload a font.
When I do so I can only upload .ttf files and by uploading the italic font all the text is written in italic.

What should I do?

```
\settextfont[Scale=1.0]{XB Yas.ttf}
\begin{document}
\textit{سلام}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to tell `fontspec` where to find the italic font:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{XB Yas.ttf}[
       BoldFont       = XB YasBd.ttf ,
       ItalicFont     = XB YasIt.ttf ,
       BoldItalicFont = XB YasBdIt.ttf]

\begin{document}
Hello! \textit{سلام}
\end{document}
```

[image]